# How do I append a dataframe to a specific level of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Consider these two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4),
                   pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B']]),
                   ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4),
                   ['C', 'D'],
                   ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])

print df1

     One  Two  Three  Four
a A    0    1      2     3
  B    4    5      6     7
b A    8    9     10    11
  B   12   13     14    15

print df2

   One  Two  Three  Four
C    0    1      2     3
D    4    5      6     7
```

I want to append `df2` to `df1` where the first level of the `df1.index` is `'a'`.

```
     One  Two  Three  Four
a A    0    1      2     3
  B    4    5      6     7
  C    0    1      2     3
  D    4    5      6     7
b A    8    9     10    11
  B   12   13     14    15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I reassign the index of `df2` with a `pd.MultiIndex` with the desired location in the first level of the index included in the new index.

```
df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a'], df2.index])
```

then `concat`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

     One  Two  Three  Four
a A    0    1      2     3
  B    4    5      6     7
  C    0    1      2     3
  D    4    5      6     7
b A    8    9     10    11
  B   12   13     14    15
```